# AttributeError while loading a Keras model containing Lambda layers

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to load a trained keras model (SeResnext) and this model architecture contains "Lambda" layers too.

Now when I try to load the model in my script I get this Attribute error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict.py", line 9, in <module>
    model = keras.models.load_model('mySeResnextModel.hdf5')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 419, in load_model
    model = _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 225, in _deserialize_model
    model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 458, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 145, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1022, in from_config
    process_layer(layer_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1008, in process_layer
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 145, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 732, in from_config
    printable_module_name='function in Lambda layer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 162, in deserialize_keras_object
    fn = module_objects.get(function_name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I think this is due to the fact that Keras don't have any inbuilt layer named Lambda, so it simply just can't identify this layer.

Now when I searched for this problem, the only and not so beneficial solution I got is to remove the lambda layer(s), but in my case, there are too many of them. Also can I import and then use Lambda layer as a custom layer?

How can I find a solution to this problem?

P.S.: I found this (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4871) after searching, how do I use custom objects parameter here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Keras has Lambda layer (`keras.layers.Lambda`) but the issue caused by a function it uses.

To resolve it you can pass required function wiht `custom_objects` argument e.g.:

```
def channel_zeropad(x, channel_axis=3):
    '''
    Zero-padding for channle dimensions.
    Note that padded channles are added like (Batch, H, W, 2/x + x + 2/x).
    '''
    shape = list(x.shape)
    y = K.zeros_like(x)

    if channel_axis == 3:
        y = y[:, :, :, :shape[channel_axis] // 2]
    else:
        y = y[:, :shape[channel_axis] // 2, :, :]

    return concatenate([y, x, y], channel_axis)

def channel_zeropad_output(input_shape, channel_axis=3):
    '''
    Function for setting a channel dimension for zero padding.
    '''
    shape = list(input_shape)
    shape[channel_axis] *= 2

    return tuple(shape)

model = keras.models.load_model('mySeResnextModel.hdf5',
              custom_objects={'channel_zeropad': channel_zeropad,
                              'channel_zeropad_output': channel_zeropad_output})
```

or define a model and its load weights separately:

```
model = SEResNeXt().model  # if you are using senet-keras
model.load_weights('mySeResnextModel.hdf5', by_name=True)
```

Comment: Can you also please tell me what function should I pass to resolve this issue, I am having problem identifying that!

Comment: I am actually trying to make a flask api with a already trained model, the code for that can be found here https://pastebin.com/N4exqsfv while the code to the model can be found here(in SeResnext heading) https://www.kaggle.com/sarques/blood-cancer-diagnosis/notebook

Comment: you can use `SEResNeXt` defined in the notebook and use `SEResNeXt().model_senet.load_weights(path)`